# Delete Topic from kafka within c++ code

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using c++ kafka implementation for C++ [rdkafka/edenhill](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka). 
The question is about topic deletion. I'am creating lots of topics with GUID  while my program is running, at the end of the program (destructors) I want to clean all those topics (there is no need for them any more).

How can I do it from within my c++ code ?

thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

Remove the all the folders that has your topic name from kafka-logs directory on kafka server. That you can do it through code in c++.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not an option since I do not know the cluster deployment. I know only the IP of one of the brokers.